# Does it make sense to use std::forward with the typeid operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, rtti, perfect-forwarding

I was wondering whether it makes sense to use `std::forward<>` when submitting an instance to `typeid`?

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T&& value) {
  std::cout << typeid(std::forward<T>(value)).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Does invoking `typeid(value)` instead yields the same result?

Comment: Why would it makes sense? Why don't you just try compiling it?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Just compiling shows that there are many cases where using `std::forward` gives the same result as not using it, but cannot be used to conclusively prove that it will give the same result in all cases.

Comment: So you write a function template like the one above and throw a load of types at it. A few built-in types, a non-trivial class type, a pointer etc and you can get pretty good idea. The first question still remains, why would it make sense? `typeid` is not a function, it doesn't copy its operand. Also, it existed in C++03 when `forward` didn't exist, so obviously `forward` isn't needed to make it give the right answer

Comment: @JonathanWakely I was actually thinking for a moment that there *might* be a subtle difference, where one of the uses returns the static type of `value`, and the other returns its dynamic type. There isn't, but if there were, it would be something you didn't list in your things to test. :) I can agree that the results of some basic testing could have been (and probably should have been) included in the question, though.

Comment: @JonathanWakely @hvd My bad, that's true I could have put some examples... Anyway, given that an expression fed to `typeid` can be evaluated at runtime and that `forward` changes the type of the expression, it did not seem that obvious to me that `forward` is superfluous in this case.

Comment: @piwi The static type of `value` is the same as the static type of `std::forward<T>(value)`: that's `T` stripped of any reference qualifiers. The dynamic type of `value` is also the same as the dynamic type of `std::forward<T>(value)`: the two expressions refer to the same object. Despite the fact that `T` can have ref-qualifiers, an expression's type is *never* a reference. It can be an lvalue, xvalue or prvalue, but that's not considered part of the expression's type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From **[expr.typeid]**/3:

> When `typeid` is applied to an expression other than a glvalue of a polymorphic class type, the result refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the static type of the expression.

In the C++ Standard, the "type of an expression" is never a reference type; the "reference-ness" (lvalue or rvalue reference) of an expression is expressed in its *value category*. Since `std::forward` does not modify the type of an expression, only its value category (e.g. from lvalue to rvalue), applying `std::forward` will not affect the result of `typeid`.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't. The result will be the same either way.